# Create table Failed: [100015] Total size of all parcels is greater than the max message size

Tags: teradata

Could someone explain what does the above error message mean? How can it be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: Well, source code is limited to 1 MB, but I can't imagine a CREATE TABLE hitting it. What are you trying to submit and how?

Comment: It's a 2 page create table statement that I am trying to run using Teradata.net connection.

Comment: Two pages, which size?

Comment: Could be the driver. I had a similar issue with JDBC drivers, which went away when I simply switched to a different version.

Comment: I have the same issue.  It's a CREATE TABLE statement.  Mine is not huge, though I do use quite a bit in the way of multi-value compression.  The SQL file is only 81 KB and it has some other SQL in it as well beyond the create table statement.  Even when I filter out most of the columns, I'm still getting the same error.  But, if I actually delete the code for those columns, then I can get it to work.  I'm using a Teradata.net connection in Teradata SQL Assistant.  I read abouta  64 KB limit elsewhere, maybe I'm hitting that?  No, that's inside a stored procedure and I'm not doing that.

Comment: Is a given query limited to 64 KB?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be two main causes of this error:

1. Bugs in the client software
2. The query is too large

Bugs:

Make sure that you have the latest tools installed.

> I have seen this error when incompatible versions of different TTU
>   software components are installed, especially CLI.
>
> Please install (or-reinstall) the latest and greatest patches of CLI.
>
> -- SteveF
>   [Steve Fineholtz Taradata Employee](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Tools-Utilities/Request-size-exceeds-maximum/td-p/48622)

The other reference is from the comments to the original post:

> Could be the driver. I had a similar issue with JDBC drivers, which went away 
>   when I simply switched to a different version. – access_granted

Query is too large:

This is the root of the problem, even if it is caused by the above bugs.

Check your actual SQL query size sent to the server.  Usually OBDC logs or debug files will let you examine the actual SQL generated.

Some SQL generators include charsets and collations to each field, increasing the query length.

You may want to create your own SQL Query from scratch.

Avoid the following, since they can be added by using additional queries.

- Indexes
- Default Values
- Constraints
- Non-ASCII characters as Column Names.

Also, [remove all whitespace except a single space](http://knowledge.teradata.com/KCS/id/KCS012105).

Do not attempt to add data while creating a table; Unless, the total size of the SQL statement is less than 1 MB.

From the [first reference](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Tools-Utilities/Request-size-exceeds-maximum/td-p/48622), the maximum query size is 1MB.

On the extreme side, you can name all of your fields a single letter(or double letters...). You can rename them with Alter Table queries later.

The same goes for type; you can set the type for all of the columns as CHAR, and modify it later(before any data is added to the table).